# Chrome input type number with minimum 0.1

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-input

HTML Number field Spinner is working wrongly in chrome version 48. On clicking 'down' when value is 0.1 it changes to 1.1. Any way to overcome this issue. I want it to stay at 0.1.

```
<input type="number" min="0.1" step="any">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/praveen2288/wmcmag5h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just wait until Google Chrome 50 is released.  This is a bug of Google Chrome and was recently fixed. [crbug.com/574066](http://crbug.com/574066)

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet shows the behavior of the `<input type="number"/>` with float values:

```html
<strong>Step 0.1</strong><br/>
<input type="number" min="0.1" step="0.1"/><br/>
<strong>Step 1.0</strong><br/>
<input type="number" min="0.1" step="1.0"/><br/>
<strong>Step 1 (not working)</strong><br/>
<input type="number" min="0.1" step="1"/><br/>
<strong>Step 'any' (not working)</strong><br/>
<input type="number" min="0.1" step="any"/><br/>
```

Comment: Agreed. What if the step is 1 or any?

Comment: Ok. I think step need to be '1.0' not simply '1' or 'any'. 'any' defaults it to '1'